# Using Pipes for bidirectional communication(Windows API)

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I am trying to write a program that supplies input to `cmd.exe` and retrieve it's output through the use of pipes.(2 Sets of pipes). However after supplying input through `PARENT_WRITE` I get no output through the other pipe, `PARENT_READ`. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>    

#define BUFFER_LENGTH 1024
void handle_cleanup(STARTUPINFOW,  PROCESS_INFORMATION);
DWORD WINAPI ReadPipe(LPVOID);

HANDLE CMD_WRITE, PARENT_READ, CMD_READ, PARENT_WRITE;

int CreateProcessCMD(void){
   DWORD ThreadID;
   DWORD bytes_written;
   HANDLE hProcessCMD;
   
   STARTUPINFOW PSTARTUPINFO;
   PROCESS_INFORMATION PPROCESSINFO;
   SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES SECURITYATTR;

   SECURITYATTR.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
   SECURITYATTR.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
   SECURITYATTR.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

   if(!CreatePipe(&PARENT_READ,&CMD_WRITE, &SECURITYATTR,0)){
       printf("Could not create pipe");
       return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }
   printf("CreatePipe(PARENT_READ, CMD_WRITE) -  Success!\n");
   
   if(!CreatePipe(&CMD_READ,&PARENT_WRITE, &SECURITYATTR,0)){
      printf("Could not create pipe");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }
   printf("CreatePipe(CMD_READ, PARENT_WRITE) - Success!\n");

   ZeroMemory(&PSTARTUPINFO, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
   printf("ZeroMemory(&PSTARTUPINFO, sizeof(STARTUPINFO) -  Zeroing STARTUPINFO structure success!\n");
   
   PSTARTUPINFO.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
   PSTARTUPINFO.hStdOutput = CMD_WRITE;
   printf("CMD_WRITE ---> %x\n", CMD_WRITE);
   printf("STARTINFO.hStsOutput ---> %x\n", PSTARTUPINFO.hStdOutput);
   PSTARTUPINFO.hStdInput = CMD_READ;
   printf("CMD_READ ---> %x\n", CMD_READ);
   printf("STARTINFO.hStdsInput ---> %x\n", PSTARTUPINFO.hStdInput);
   PSTARTUPINFO.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
   PSTARTUPINFO.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
   PSTARTUPINFO.wShowWindow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;
   BOOL success = CreateProcessW(L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
                      NULL,
                      NULL,
                      NULL,
                      TRUE,
                      NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
                      NULL,
                      NULL,
                      &PSTARTUPINFO,
                      &PPROCESSINFO);
   if(!success){
      printf("CreateProcessW() --> Could not create process!\n");
      printf("[-] Closing program");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }
   
   printf("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe started with PID ---> %i\n", PPROCESSINFO.dwProcessId);

   HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ReadPipe, NULL, 0, &ThreadID);
   if(hThread == NULL){
      printf("CreateThread() --> Failed, Returned %i\n", GetLastError());
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }
   printf("CreateThread() --> New thread created with TID --> %i\n", ThreadID);
   Sleep(2000);
      
   while(TRUE){   
      char cmd[256];
      printf("Prompt> ");
      gets(cmd);
      WriteFile(PARENT_WRITE, cmd, strlen(cmd), &bytes_written, NULL);
      printf("WriteFile() --> Wrote %i bytes\n", bytes_written);
   }
   
   hProcessCMD = PPROCESSINFO.hProcess;
   switch (WaitForSingleObject(hProcessCMD, INFINITE))
   {
   case WAIT_ABANDONED :
      printf("WaitForSingleObject(hProcess, Timeout) ---> Returned WAIT_ABANDONED\n");
      break;
   case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
      printf("WaitForSingleObject(hProcess, Timeout) ---> The state of the specified object is signaled (Process has terminated)\n");
      break;
   case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
      printf("WaitForSingleObject(hProcess, Timeout) ---> Returned WAIT_TIMEOUT\n");
      break;
   case WAIT_FAILED:
      printf("WaitForSingleObject(hProcess, Timeout) ---> Failed, Returned &i\n", GetLastError());
      break;
   default:
      break;
   }
   

   handle_cleanup(PSTARTUPINFO, PPROCESSINFO);
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int main(void){

   printf("Parent PID ------> %u\n", GetCurrentProcessId());
   if(CreateProcessCMD()){
      printf("CreateProcessCMD() - Function returned EXIT_FAILURE\n");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void handle_cleanup(STARTUPINFOW startupinfo,  PROCESS_INFORMATION  processinfo ){
    if(!CloseHandle(startupinfo.hStdInput)) printf("[-] Could not close stdin handle\n");
    if(!CloseHandle(startupinfo.hStdOutput)) printf("[-] Could not close stdout handle\n");
    if(!CloseHandle(startupinfo.hStdError)) printf("[-] Could not close stderr handle\n");
    if(!CloseHandle(processinfo.hProcess)) printf("[-] Could not close process handle\n");
    if(!CloseHandle(processinfo.hThread)) printf("[-] Could not close thread handle\n");
}


DWORD  WINAPI ReadPipe(LPVOID lpThreadParameter){
     char buffer[BUFFER_LENGTH];
     
     DWORD bytes_read_from_pipe;
     while(TRUE) {
        int ret = ReadFile(PARENT_READ, buffer, BUFFER_LENGTH, &bytes_read_from_pipe, NULL);
        printf("ReadFile() --> Read %i\n", bytes_read_from_pipe);
        if(bytes_read_from_pipe>0){
           printf("%s\n", buffer);
           ZeroMemory(buffer, BUFFER_LENGTH);
           bytes_read_from_pipe = 0;
           continue;
        }
        break;
   }
}
```

And the output:

```
Parent PID ------> 12064
CreatePipe(PARENT_READ, CMD_WRITE) -  Success!
CreatePipe(CMD_READ, PARENT_WRITE) - Success!
ZeroMemory(&PSTARTUPINFO, sizeof(STARTUPINFO) -  Zeroing STARTUPINFO structure success!
CMD_WRITE ---> 100
STARTINFO.hStsOutput ---> 100
CMD_READ ---> 104
STARTINFO.hStdsInput ---> 104
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe started with PID ---> 8700
CreateThread() --> New thread created with TID --> 16680
ReadFile() --> Read 43
Microsoft Windows [Version ...]
ReadFile() --> Read 89

(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\<USER>\Sandbox\>
Prompt> where calc.exe
WriteFile() --> Wrote 14 bytes
Prompt>
WriteFile() --> Wrote 0 bytes
```

I seem to be able to write to it and cannot seem to be able to retrieve any output, `ReadFile()` Simple hangs

I am fairly new to the Windows API

Comment: It is still waiting for the command, you forgot to write the Enter key press.

Comment: Aside: You should also set `PSTARTUPINFO.hStdError` to something, e.g. `PSTARTUPINFO.hStdError = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);`.

Comment: `gets(cmd);` will replace the `'\n'` at the end of the read line to `'\0'`. `fgets` does not replace the `'\n'`. Also `gets` is deprecated and unsafe.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: use synchronous bidirectional pipes almost always lead to deadlock. correct solution - use asynchronous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Hans Passant said, you forgot to write the Enter key press.

After adding this:

[image]

```
strcat_s(cmd, "\r\n");
```

it will work fine.

[image]