# Can't write to Windows Named Pipe after read operation or vice versa

Tags: winapi, named-pipes

I'm trying to have echo service over Windows Named Pipes, this means that what ever data(in any length) that is sent to the server over pipe should be returned over the same pipe.
Both Client -> Server and Server -> Client needs to have [length][data].

I asked related question here [Reading variable length data over Windows Named Pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76934686/reading-variable-length-data-over-windows-named-pipes)

With some help I could fix my code to be able to read variable length data over the pipe. My current code works for one side, Client to Server but I cannot write to the pipe that I was reading from it or vice versa! I get error code 109. The pipe server and pipe clients are different applications.

I didn't included the source code that is already listed in the above link again here I hope that is fine.

Thanks

Comment: fter you got ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE you need call DisconnectNamedPipe and than ConnectNamedPipe if you want continue use it or CloseHandle

Comment: Yeah but why? I do not close any handle myself! On server side after ReadFile I call WriteFile right a way and I have my client code in a while (1) loop and CloseHandle(pipe) is after the loop break.

Comment: Does this help?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76272852/using-pipes-for-bidirectional-communicationwindows-api/76286542#76286542